# Why does the resizing of the content does not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, browser, resize, fits

The Code makes that every content fits to the size of the browser. It works perfectly in webkit so:

Why does this not function in Firefox ?

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
resizeDiv();
};

function resizeDiv() {
vph = $(window).height();
$('#content').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content1').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content2').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content3').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content4').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content5').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content6').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content7').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content8').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
$('#content9').css({'min-height': vph + 'px'});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to jquery,this should work:

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
    resizeDiv();
    });
```

Otherwise in plain javascript:

```
window.onresize=resizeDiv;
```

should be enough for all browsers.

Comment: no, did not work out. in every content there is an image and firefox extend the size of the contents to the size of the image not the size of the browserwindow. So the content is bigger than the browserwindow while webkit sizes everything fine.